How do I properly insert Javascript into Wordpress 2024 Block Theme
I have created a warning page for a website. I now want to set session storage via javascript because I don't want the warning page to load every time the user navigates to a different page on the website. I have put everything in the footer and it loads via shortcode. While the Warning Page loads correctly, the Javascript is not executing because the theme is inserting   <p> </p> tags in my script which is kicking out an error in the console, Syntax error unexpected < found. What is the correct way to insert the script so that it executes correctly?
    function eb_disclaimer () { 
    ob_start();
?>
    
    <div id="disclaimer" style="position: fixed; z-index: 1; left: 0; top:0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; background-color: rgb(0,0,0); background-color: rgb(0,0,0, 1)">
        <div style="text-align: center;"><h1> </h1></div>
        <div style="text-align: center;"><h3> </h3></div>
        <img style="display: block; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;" src=" " title=""/>
        <div style="margin: 0 20px 0 20px;" >blah blah blah</div>
        <button id="close_disclaimer" style="display: block; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; background-color: rgb(229, 184, 11); border-radius: 6px; height: 44px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255)" onclick="eb_start_session()">Confirm</button>
    </div>
    <script>if (sessionStorage.getItem('website') !== null ){document.getElementById("disclaimer").style.display = 'none';console.log('yes')}else{document.getElementById("disclaimer").style.display = true;console.log('no')}</script>
    <script>function eb_start_session () { sessionStorage.setItem('website','value');document.getElementById('disclaimer').style.display='none'}</script>
<?php
    $disclaimer = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    
    return $disclaimer;
    
}
add_shortcode('disclaimer', 'eb_disclaimer');


How did you add the shortcode and what is handling it?

Hi, created a custom-shortcodes.php file and placed it in my child theme. I added include('custom-shortcodes.php') to my functions file in my child theme.
What I did to get it to work in the interim, is to write the javascript without any spaces and that seemed to do the trick.

You should add the function, which handles the shortcode (from custom-shortcodes.php) to your question then.

The issue with paragraph tags being inserted, like means the content gets send through the the_content filter. "I have put everything in the footer and it loads via shortcode." - can you explain what exactly that looks like? Did you use do_shortcode in your footer template, or where / how was it embedded?

The 2024 Wordpress theme uses blocks. I add the shortcode block and then in there I place the name [disclaimer]. I have used a shortcode in a similar way to call and display my custom fields.
